# Oracle ANSI left outer join with more than 1050 columns in 11gR2

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have an issue on Oracle (11.2.0.1.0) where too many left outer joins (or rather too many columns in the joined tables) results in the following error:

`ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel`

The alert.log file shows the underlying error as:

`ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump`...

We have seen a similar issue before, but under a different error:

`ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a
key-preserved table`

[When ANSI SQL Join Syntax Does Not Work in Oracle](http://awads.net/wp/2007/06/14/when-ansi-sql-join-syntax-does-not-work-in-oracle/)

[ORA-01445](http://www.halfcooked.com/mt/archives/000936.html)

Test case:

```
-- create 100 colum table
CREATE TABLE BIG_TABLE
(
  c1 NVARCHAR2(1), c2 NVARCHAR2(1), c3 NVARCHAR2(1), c4 NVARCHAR2(1), c5 NVARCHAR2(1), c6 NVARCHAR2(1), c7 NVARCHAR2(1), c8 NVARCHAR2(1), c9 NVARCHAR2(1), c10 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c11 NVARCHAR2(1), c12 NVARCHAR2(1), c13 NVARCHAR2(1), c14 NVARCHAR2(1), c15 NVARCHAR2(1), c16 NVARCHAR2(1), c17 NVARCHAR2(1), c18 NVARCHAR2(1), c19 NVARCHAR2(1), c20 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c21 NVARCHAR2(1), c22 NVARCHAR2(1), c23 NVARCHAR2(1), c24 NVARCHAR2(1), c25 NVARCHAR2(1), c26 NVARCHAR2(1), c27 NVARCHAR2(1), c28 NVARCHAR2(1), c29 NVARCHAR2(1), c30 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c31 NVARCHAR2(1), c32 NVARCHAR2(1), c33 NVARCHAR2(1), c34 NVARCHAR2(1), c35 NVARCHAR2(1), c36 NVARCHAR2(1), c37 NVARCHAR2(1), c38 NVARCHAR2(1), c39 NVARCHAR2(1), c40 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c41 NVARCHAR2(1), c42 NVARCHAR2(1), c43 NVARCHAR2(1), c44 NVARCHAR2(1), c45 NVARCHAR2(1), c46 NVARCHAR2(1), c47 NVARCHAR2(1), c48 NVARCHAR2(1), c49 NVARCHAR2(1), c50 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c51 NVARCHAR2(1), c52 NVARCHAR2(1), c53 NVARCHAR2(1), c54 NVARCHAR2(1), c55 NVARCHAR2(1), c56 NVARCHAR2(1), c57 NVARCHAR2(1), c58 NVARCHAR2(1), c59 NVARCHAR2(1), c60 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c61 NVARCHAR2(1), c62 NVARCHAR2(1), c63 NVARCHAR2(1), c64 NVARCHAR2(1), c65 NVARCHAR2(1), c66 NVARCHAR2(1), c67 NVARCHAR2(1), c68 NVARCHAR2(1), c69 NVARCHAR2(1), c70 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c71 NVARCHAR2(1), c72 NVARCHAR2(1), c73 NVARCHAR2(1), c74 NVARCHAR2(1), c75 NVARCHAR2(1), c76 NVARCHAR2(1), c77 NVARCHAR2(1), c78 NVARCHAR2(1), c79 NVARCHAR2(1), c80 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c81 NVARCHAR2(1), c82 NVARCHAR2(1), c83 NVARCHAR2(1), c84 NVARCHAR2(1), c85 NVARCHAR2(1), c86 NVARCHAR2(1), c87 NVARCHAR2(1), c88 NVARCHAR2(1), c89 NVARCHAR2(1), c90 NVARCHAR2(1), 
  c91 NVARCHAR2(1), c92 NVARCHAR2(1), c93 NVARCHAR2(1), c94 NVARCHAR2(1), c95 NVARCHAR2(1), c96 NVARCHAR2(1), c97 NVARCHAR2(1), c98 NVARCHAR2(1), c99 NVARCHAR2(1), c100 NVARCHAR2(1)
)
/

-- left outer join query (10 joins = 1000 columns)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  BIG_TABLE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT1 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT2 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT3 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT4 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT5 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT6 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT7 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT8 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT9 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT10 ON 1 = 1
  --LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT11 ON 1 = 1
```

If you uncomment the last line, it will result in the error.

--

I have tested against the following versions:

**10.2.0.1.0** = ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from a join view wihtout a key-preserved table.

*(Please note that you need to comment out the last TWO joins to make this work - it seems to include the first table's columns in addition to the joined tables)*

**11.1.0.6.0** = O.K.

**11.2.0.1.0** = ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Can someone please confirm my results (the last result especially) and if possible, suggest any workarounds?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Joining without a join condition (`ON 1 = 1`) is **not** an outer join, it is an obfuscated way to write a `cross join`

Comment: It does also seem relevant that a situation with a query with too many columns for Oracle 10 or lower to handle needs have the database refactored. Yes, that sentence is horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your test case and I found some results:
1) you are doing a cartesian product if you insert 2 rows into big table the query outputs 4096 rows, I don't know if this was the desired behaviour
2)if you limit the unmber of selected columns to 96 you get the results.
I tried

```
SELECT
  big_table.c1,big_table.c2,big_table.c3,big_table.c4,big_table.c5,big_table.c6,big_table.c7,big_table.c8,big_table.c9,big_table.c10,
  big_table.c11,big_table.c12,big_table.c13,big_table.c14,big_table.c15,big_table.c16,big_table.c17,big_table.c18,big_table.c19,big_table.c20,
  big_table.c21,big_table.c22,big_table.c23,big_table.c24,big_table.c25,big_table.c26,big_table.c27,big_table.c28,big_table.c29,big_table.c30,
  big_table.c31,big_table.c32,big_table.c33,big_table.c34,big_table.c35,big_table.c36,big_table.c37,big_table.c38,big_table.c39,big_table.c40,
  big_table.c41,big_table.c42,big_table.c43,big_table.c44,big_table.c45,big_table.c46,big_table.c47,big_table.c48,big_table.c49,big_table.c50,
  big_table.c51,big_table.c52,big_table.c53,big_table.c54,big_table.c55,big_table.c56,big_table.c57,big_table.c58,big_table.c59,big_table.c60,
  big_table.c61,big_table.c62,big_table.c63,big_table.c64,big_table.c65,big_table.c66,big_table.c67,big_table.c68,big_table.c69,big_table.c70,
  big_table.c71,big_table.c72,big_table.c73,big_table.c74,big_table.c75,big_table.c76,big_table.c77,big_table.c78,big_table.c79,big_table.c80,
  big_table.c81,big_table.c82,big_table.c83,big_table.c84,big_table.c85,big_table.c86,big_table.c87,big_table.c88,big_table.c89,big_table.c90,
  big_table.c91,big_table.c92,big_table.c93,big_table.c94,big_table.c95,big_table.c96
FROM
BIG_TABLE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT1 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT2 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT3 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT4 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT5 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT6 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT7 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT8 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT9 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT10 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BIG_TABLE BT11 ON 1 = 1
```

and got no error
with 97 columns or more I got the error you mention. 
I think you are hitting a bug, so if you have access to Metalink try to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I can confirm your findings - thanks. That was just an example query, we do have a "real world" query that fails for (seemingly) the same reason!

Comment: It seems as though simply select big_table.c1 and "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY big_table.c1 ASC) RN" will also result in the error. Fabulous!

Comment: you are hitting a lot of Oracle bugs with your sql, patch the installation if you can

Answer (score 4):

Works fine in 11.2.0.3 on Linux x86-64.
So, I recommend you upgrade 11.2.0.1.0 -> 11.2.0.3.0.
Not only will it fix this bug, but also thousands of other bugs, as well.
Also, if you open an SR w/ Oracle, first thing they do, they'll request you upgrade to 11.2.0.3.

-Mark

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately we're not on Linux and don't have access to that version regardless - but it is good to know this and other bugs have been fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your test case worked for me. I even added five more left outer joins and that worked. Our instance may have some patches installed, I'm not sure.

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
```

> ```
> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
> PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
> CORE  11.2.0.1.0  Production
> TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
> NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. login as sysdba
2. run this command:

   ```
   alter system set "_query_rewrite_vop_cleanup" = false
   ```

this will fix your problem on 11.2.0.1 without upgrade

Comment: This fix is documented in Bug #10242303 and Bug #10184115